# Не работает дружественная функция

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, функции

В книге Герберта Шилдта используется такой пример :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int IDLE=0;

const int INUSE=1;

class С2; // опережающее объявление

class C1 {

　　int status; // IDLE если сообщение неактивно, INUSE если сообщение выведено на экран.

　　// ...

　public:

　　void set_status(int state);

　　friend int idle(C1 a, C2 b);

};

class C2 {

　　int status; // IDLE если сообщение неактивно, INUSE если сообщение выведено на экран.

　　// ...

　public:

　　void set_status(int state);

　　friend int idle(C1 a, C2 b);

};

void C1::set_status(int state)

{

　status = state;

}

void C2::set_status(int state)

{

　status = state;

}

// Функция idle() - "друг" для классов C1 и C2.

int idle(C1 a, C2 b)

{

　if(a.status || b.status) return 0;

　else return 1;

}

int main()

{

　C1 x;

　C2 y;

　x.set_status(IDLE);

　y.set_status(IDLE);

　if(idle(x, y)) cout << "Экран свободен.\n";

　else cout << "Отображается сообщение.\n";

　x.set_status(INUSE);

　if(idle(x, y)) cout << "Экран свободен.\n";

　else cout << "Отображается сообщение.\n";

　return 0;

}
```

Компилятор выдает, что невозможно обратиться к private члену, объявленному в классе C1, хотя функция `idle` объявлена дружественной. Ошибку выдает в определении функции `idle` вот в этой строке `status` возле `a.` подсвечивается красным :

```
if (a.status || b.status) return 0;
```

В чем ошибка и как это исправить?

Comment: Стоило заменить русскую C на латинскую в предварительном объявлении `C2`, как все заработало: https://ideone.com/z1RV9j

Comment: Я догадывался, что такое может быть, но казалось все, что мог поменять, поменял, а ведь нет)

Comment: В любом случае "подсвечивается красным" - еще не повод судить о наличии ошибки. Компилировать надо и смотреть на сообщения компилятора.